# How to set alert show popup just one time?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a script that check pathItem and show an alert if condition is wrong, but if there is more than 1 mistake, the alert will display as many time it is. I just want it show only once. How do I fix it?

[image: Alert 1]
[image: Alert 2]

```
#target photoshop  
    
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var pLen = doc.pathItems.length;
var pArray = [];
          
for(var i=0;i<pLen;i++){
    pArray.push(doc.pathItems[i].name)
    }
    
for(var i=0;i<pLen;i++){
    var curPath = doc.pathItems.getByName (pArray[i]);
    
        if(curPath.name == 'Freistellerpfad' && curPath.kind == "PathKind.CLIPPINGPATH") 
        {}
    else if (curPath.name == 'Ausschnitt BR' && curPath.kind == "PathKind.NORMALPATH")
        {}
    else    {alert(doc.name + '\n' + "Wrong path" + '\n' + pArray[i])}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't sure if that was possible, but I got it to work. The key here is `displayDialogs` which can be set to ALL, ERROR or NO.

So now we need to create an error: In my example we deliberate create an error (by sampling a colour that's off the image)  And then correct it.

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // ON

// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

var x = -1;
var y = 2;

// loop over three times, only see the error once.
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  try
  {
    var pointSample = srcDoc.colorSamplers.add([x,y]);
  }
  catch (eek)
  {
    //It's going wrong
    // Switch off the dialog
    displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF
    alert("eek"); // should see this once
    x = 2; //correct the error
  }
}

// Set Display Dialogs back to normal
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // NORMAL
```

Note that setting `displayDialogs` will affect the next script that's run. Useful for switching off if you ever have any scripts with text :D